# Restler OAuth2 server

Tags: php, oauth, restler

I have server login to my site. I use for API Restler 3 with OAuth2.

Server.php:

```
    <?php

namespace Auth;
use Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate;
use OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials;
use OAuth2\Storage\Pdo;
use OAuth2\Server as OAuth2Server;
use OAuth2\GrantType\AuthorizationCode;
use OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials;
use OAuth2\Request;
use OAuth2\Response;
/**
 * Class Server
 *
 * @package OAuth2
 *
 */

class Server implements iAuthenticate
{
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $dbName = DB_NAME;
    private $user = DB_LOGIN;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;

    /**
     * @var OAuth2Server
     */
    protected static $server;
    /**
     * @var Pdo
     */
    protected static $storage;
    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    protected static $request;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $dns = "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset=utf8";
        static::$storage = new PDO(
            array('dsn' => $dns, 'username' => $this->user, 'password' => $this->pass)
        );

        $grantTypes = array(
            'authorization_code' => new AuthorizationCode(static::$storage),
            'user_credentials'   => new UserCredentials(static::$storage),
        );
        static::$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        static::$server = new OAuth2Server(
            static::$storage,
            array('enforce_state' => true, 'allow_implicit' => true),
            $grantTypes
        );
        $grantType = new ClientCredentials(static::$storage);
        static::$server->addGrantType($grantType);
    }

    /**
     * Stage 2: User response is captured here
     *
     * Success or failure is communicated back to the Client using the redirect
     * url provided by the client
     *
     * On success authorization code is sent along
     *
     *
     * @param bool $authorize
     *
     * @return \OAuth2\Response
     *
     * @format JsonFormat,UploadFormat
     */
    public function postAuthorize($authorize = false)
    {
        static::$server->handleAuthorizeRequest(
            static::$request,
            new Response(),
            (bool)$authorize
        )->send();
        exit;
    }
    /**
     * Stage 3: Client directly calls this api to exchange access token
     *
     * It can then use this access token to make calls to protected api
     *
     * @format JsonFormat,UploadFormat
     * @access public
     * @url POST apiMobile/grand
     * @url GET apiMobile/rer
     */
    public function postGrant()
    {
        static::$server->handleTokenRequest(static::$request)->send();
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Access verification method.
     *
     * API access will be denied when this method returns false
     *
     * @return boolean true when api access is allowed; false otherwise
     */
    public function __isAllowed()
    {
        $token = static::$server->getAccessTokenData(Request::createFromGlobals());

        global $idClient;

        $idClient = $token['client_id'];

        return self::$server->verifyResourceRequest(static::$request);
    }
    public function __getWWWAuthenticateString()
    {
        return 'auth string';
    }
}
?>
```

And init.php:

```
<?php
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
class ApiMode
{
    private $class = '';
    private $function = '';

    public function __construct($controller = DEFAULT_CONTROLLER, $function = DEFAULT_FUNCTION)
    {
        $this->class = $controller;
        $this->function = $function;

        $controllerClass = ucfirst($this->class).CONTROLLER_TERMINAL;
        $controllerPatch = CONTROLLER_DIR.'/'.$controllerClass.'.php';
        require_once $controllerPatch;

        require_once EXTERN_DIR.'/OAuth2/Autoloader.php';
        OAuth2\Autoloader::register();
        require_once EXTERN_DIR.'/vendor/restler.php';
        require_once CLASS_DIR.'/Server.php';


        $r = new Restler();


        $r->addAuthenticationClass('Auth\\Server', '');
        $r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'XmlFormat');//, 
        $r->addAPIClass($controllerClass,'');
        $r->setOverridingFormats('JsonFormat');
        $r->setOverridingFormats('UploadFormat');
        $r->handle();
    }
}
?>
```

I use only Stage 3 - postGrand to get access token.
From web browser on http://mypage/apiMobile/rer.json (GET is for test from my web browser if GET work, POST work well) get:
local server Windows (this is OK):

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request method must be POST when requesting an access token","error_uri":"http:\/\/tools.ietf.org\/html\/rfc6749#section-3.2"}
```

web server (use https) Linux PHP 5.5.21 (fail):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "debug": {
        "source": "Routes.php:438 at route stage",
        "stages": {
            "success": [
                "get"
            ],
            "failure": [
                "route",
                "negotiate",
                "message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

On web server and local work all from API (address: mypage/apiMobile/myApi.json from controller):

```
$r->addAPIClass($controllerClass,'');
```

Main problem is with access to OAuth2 (I need access from http://mypage/apiMobile/rer.json). Any idea or tutorial?

Thanks.